# JavaFX HTMLEditor - focus webView (TextArea)

Tags: java, javafx, webview, focus

I have created a chat using the JavaFX HTMLEditor Component, after sending a message the Editor isn't focused anymore since you press the send button which is focused for the moment). I'd like to somehow focus the editor, I have already Googled but didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  void editorWebViewRequestFocus()
  {
    final WebView view = (WebView) ((GridPane) ((HTMLEditorSkin) editor.getSkin()).getChildren().get( 0 )).getChildren().get( 2 );

    Platform.runLater( () ->
    {
      view.fireEvent( new MouseEvent( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, 100, 100, 200, 200, MouseButton.PRIMARY, 1, false, false, false, false,
          false, false, false, false, false, false, null ) );
      editor.requestFocus();
      view.fireEvent( new MouseEvent( MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, 100, 100, 200, 200, MouseButton.PRIMARY, 1, false, false, false, false,
          false, false, false, false, false, false, null ) );
    } );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  WebView webView = (WebView) htmlEditor.lookup("WebView");
    ((HTMLBodyElementImpl) ((NodeListImpl) webView.getEngine().getDocument().getElementsByTagName("body")).item(0)).focus();
```

In addition to focus, you can set and get text and much more